# (Smarty) Function preg_match or another best way

Tags: php, preg-match, smarty

What is the best way in smarty to create a function to parse a name?

example:
I have the variable {$attachment.filename}

If the file name is .jpg|.jpeg|.gif|.png
--- my result --- (option to open in lightbox... else no option to open in lightbox...)

Thanks!

Comment: Write a plugin. Your question is too broad to be answered here.

Comment: In php I use this:
if(preg_match('/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)(?:[\?\#].*)?$/i', $attachment["filename"], $matches))

and in smarty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the parsing in PHP and set a flag in a Smarty variable. In the template check the flag and display what you need. Don't embed logic in templates.

If you really need this functionality in many templates you can, indeed, write a Smarty plugin that suits your needs.

The documentation about [Smarty plugins](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.tpl) includes examples that can inspire you.

For example:

```
// Define the function that implements the plugin
function my_special_img($params, Smarty_Internal_Template $template)
{
    $src = $params['src'];
    // Based on $src decide here if you want lightbox or not
    $lightbox = TRUE;       // or FALSE

    // Generate the <img> element
    // Get information from $params, put default values, do whatever you want
    $output = implode(' ', array(      // build the string from pieces
        '<img',
          'src="{$src}"',
          'width="{$params['width']}"',
          'height="{$params['height']"',
          'alt="{$params['alt']}"',
          'class="{$params['class']}"',
          ($lightbox ? 'rel="lightbox"' : ''),
        '/>'
    ));

    // Smarty will replace the function call in the template with the value it returns
    return $output;
}

// Register the plugin in Smarty
$smarty->registerPlugin('function', 'image', 'my_special_img');
```

In the templates, replace

```
<img src="filename.jpg" width="40" alt="bla-bla" etc>
```

with

```
{image src="filename.jpg" width="40" alt="bla-bla" etc}
```

That's all. Express your creativity in the plugin's code but keep it simple and use only the values provided in `$params`.